# Dynamically add images in deployed Meteor app

Tags: deployment, meteor

I have a deployed Meteor app that allows my admin users to upload images, audio, and video. I use [meteor-uploads](https://github.com/tomitrescak/meteor-uploads) to upload the files, optimize the media, and place into public/images, public/video, etc.

However, though the media files are placed in the correct location, the app doesn't see them -- though it does see other files in public/images that were deployed.

```
root@doc# pwd
/home/secrethistory/bundle/programs/web.browser/app
root@doc# ls images/menuburger.png  images/add.png
images/add.png  images/menuburger.png
```

Apparently, in order to hot deploy these images, I need to register them with Meteor. How do I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by **"app doesn't see them -"** ??, have you tried accessing __localhost:3000/images/menuberger.png__, for example

Comment: I can see them locally since Meteor dynamically reloads for file changes or additions locally. But deployed, `mysever.domain.com/images/menuburger.png` offers a 'file not found'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a new challenge, and I stumbled across a few workarounds.

Apparently, Meteor will not let you add assets on the fly since they have to be in meteor's manifest for it to serve them.

The most straightforward solution is to serve your "public" files separately. With nginx, for instance, in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/yourwebsite` we configure node to serve media files outside of meteor.

```
location /audio/ {
    root /home/secrethistory/bundle/programs/web.browser/app;
}
location /video/ {
    root /home/secrethistory/bundle/programs/web.browser/app;
}
location /images/ {
    root /home/secrethistory/bundle/programs/web.browser/app;
}
```